# Solar cell driven transistors - circuit explanation

Tags: transistors, solar-cell

Question: what is the purpose of resistor R23 with value 1Mohm?

Schematic of solar cell driven circuit is below.

Circuit works as follows:
When solar cell voltage is higher than 0.7V , LED is OFF 
When solar voltage is lower than 0,7V, LED is shining with low intensity powered from battery.

[image: circuit with 2 transistors]

Output voltage simulated with circuitlab:
[image: simulated output]

Comment: Pretty sure it has no use, as its impedance is so much higher than the base/emitter of Q3.

Comment: This schematic is a mess! Put high voltages at top, low ones at bottom, and logical flow left to right to the extent you reasonably can.  The sideways transistors and gratuitous looping around is wasting people's time here, and is *not* appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for a messy schematic. I dont design circuit schematics. This is just a partial circuit of already existing solar lamp. I am just trying to understand it and is not intended to be misleading.
Understanding is necessary to connect the external circuit (atmel328p) to create a connected and controlled Internet device. Thank you for your assistance in understanding how the circuit operates.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of that resistor would be as a 'pull down' resistor, to give a path to gnd fkr the PV current when it's prodicing less than the necessary ~1uA to cause an 0.7V voltage drop across the 1M resistor & reach the 0.7V required to forward-bias the BE junction of Q3.

PV cells' output power varies more in the realm of current than of open-circuit voltage, so it's necessary to provide a resistor to 'set the threshold.' If you lower the value of R23 it will raise the amount of light that it takes hitting the PV to generate anough current to turn off the led.

Answer (score 0):

R23 is only to ensure that Q3 is really off when there is little light.  It reduces the influence external noise would have to turn on the transistor when it shouldn't be on.  Personally, I would probably have made R23 lower, like 100 kΩ, but I don't know the specs of the solar cell.